# Android: Show Action Bar if supported

Tags: android

Is it possible to have the action bar show on systems using the Android 3.0 API or greater, but to gracefully ignore it otherwise (since pre-3.0, handsets required a menu button and an Action Bar wouldn't be necessary).

The showAsAction XML attribute isn't part of the old APIs. I thought of using reflection, but there's no setShowAsAction() method or equivalent for menu items.

Comment: You could maybe be interested by the `ActionBarSherlock`, with this you'll be able to have the ActionBar in pre 3.0 application, it can be found [here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Answer (score 4):

You can programmatically get the current API level via: `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;` Or make two layout files with actionBar and with no ActionBar and put them into `layout` and `layout-v11` Folder. All Devices with 3.0 and higher will automatically use the one in layout-v11
Or you can use the [ActionBar Sherlock Library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to make the ActionBar available in Devices with lower API level.

Comment: Turns out I hadn't set the targetSdkVersion in the Manifest. Thanks for the response, but the solution was even simpler.